# Is their any way to access arguments from shell script to React JS app?

Tags: reactjs, bash, powershell, shell, google-chrome

I have created a .sh file in a React app. When I run command "npm run app" the file executes. Now what I am trying to do here is, whenever I run that "npm run app arg1 arg2" command it takes arguments and I can access those arguments inside .sh file using "$1", "$2" Whichis working fine. After that I am running below code which helps me to launch "chrome browser" from .sh file.

```
start chrome --chrome-frame --user-data-dir="%tmp%\chrome_tmp_user_dir~%RANDOM%" --window-size=500,660 --window-position=550,100 --app="http://localhost:8080
```

Now what I want is a way to pass those arguments to the url which I can access inside a React App and those arguments should not visible in URL bar. Now when I run below code

```
start chrome --chrome-frame --user-data-dir="%tmp%\chrome_tmp_user_dir~%RANDOM%" --window-size=500,660 --window-position=550,100 --app="http://localhost:8080/?param1=$1&param2=$2"
```

I am able to pass those arguments successfully to React app but the issue is those are visible in URL, as you can see in below image.

[image]

Is their any way to hide those arguments so it should not be visible to user ?

Comment: From what I understand, the whole question boils down to how to invoke chrome in such a way, that it is directed to a certain page, but does not show the URL. Hence, I would remove from you question the irrelevant tags _javascript_, _reacjs_, _powershell_ and _shell_, and add the important tag _chrome_. Since the problem here is how to operate chrome from the command line, I would consider asking this at [su] and not at [so].

Comment: `".....chrome.exe"  "--app=http://google.com?t=456&q=123"` - this starts in application mode and does not shows anything except window title and close button. BUT if the url is invalid, it starts chrome in normal mode. Seems that your args contain special symbols and it breaks everything. Try encoding args like this `[System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode('@Some & Symbols')`